# java displaying List element as string

Tags: java, arrays, list, tostring

I am following a Stream tutorial but I do not understand what I need to do to have the List elements output the content as the numbers contained within.

> *Given two lists of numbers, how would you return all pairs of numbers? For example, given a list [1, 2, 3] and a list [3, 4] you should return [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 4)]. For simplicity, you can represent a pair as an array with two elements.*

I have read a few posts about overriding toString() but I have no object to override. I am clearly missing something about the nature of 'pairs', is it because 'pairs' is a List of int[][]?

```
package testcode;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class TestCode {

public TestCode(){
    testStream();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestCode tC = new TestCode();
}

public void testStream(){
    List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(3,4);
    List<int[]> pairs = numbers1.stream()
            .flatMap(i -> numbers2.stream()
                    .map(j -> new int[]{i, j})
            )
            .collect(toList());
    pairs.forEach(System.out::println);
//I have also tried 
    //String a = Arrays.toString(pairs); // but no suitable method found.
    String list = pairs.toString();
    System.out.println("list = " + list);
//tried converting pairs element to a List<String> using concatenation to force it be a string.
    List<String> stringsList  = new ArrayList<String>(pairs.size()); 
    for (int i = 0 ; i < pairs.size() ; i++) {
        stringsList.add("" + pairs.get(i));   
    }
    stringsList.forEach(System.out::println);
// or   
    System.out.println(" ** test 2");
    String[] stringsList2  = new String[pairs.size()]; 
    for (int i = 0 ; i < pairs.size() ; i++) {
        stringsList2[i] = "" + pairs.get(i);
        System.out.println(stringsList2[i]);
    }
}
```

Cheers for reading.

Comment: the code I used:
     pairs.forEach(pair -> System.out.println("(" + pair[0] + ", " + pair[1] + ")"));

Comment: You should consider using `printf` for printing you pairs: `System.out.printf("(%d,%d)\n",pair[0],pair[1]))`. It might just be my opinion, but it looks a bit cleaner than all that string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a nested `for` loop to cycle through the arrays and concatenate casted strings.

```
public static String test_method() {
    int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] array2 = {3, 4};

    String string = "";

    for (int i: array1) {
        for (int j: array2) {
            String sub = "(" + String.valueOf(i) + ", " 
                             + String.valueOf(j) + ") ";
            string += sub;
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```

Comment: You can of course iterate through a `List` object too.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.deepToString(Object[] a)` should accomplish what you need.

`deepToString` will recursively print the elements of a multidimensional array.

### Example

**Code**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] test = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(test));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```